# How to put a random number arraylist in an array?

Tags: java

on the part of

```
if(boton == cartas[0]){

                    cartas[0].setLabel(figuras[Memorando.list.get(i)]);
                }
```

in my code I'm trying to put a random number that I generated before but when the applet launches it gives me an error when I press the button, I want to put that code in all the buttons because I don't want repeated numbers, I want a randomly generated number for every button. I hope you can help me.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Memorando extends Applet implements ActionListener {
    JButton cartas[];
    JButton juegoNuevo;
    Label marcador;
    public static ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static ArrayList<Integer> random() {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            list.add(new Integer(i));
        }
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
        return list;
    }

    public void init(){
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        Font appletFont=new Font("Monospased", Font.BOLD, 20);
        this.setFont(appletFont);
        juegoNuevo=new JButton("Juego nuevo");
        juegoNuevo.addActionListener(this);
        Panel topPanel=new Panel();
        topPanel.add(juegoNuevo);
        this.add(topPanel,"North");
        cartas=new JButton[8];

        Panel panelCentral=new Panel();
        panelCentral.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,4));
        this.add(panelCentral,"Center");
        marcador=new Label("No has ganado aun :(");
        this.add(marcador,"South");
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
            cartas[i]=new JButton("*********");
            cartas[i].addActionListener(this);
        cartas[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            panelCentral.add(cartas[i]);
        }
    }



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        JButton boton=(JButton) e.getSource();


        String[] figuras=new String[8];
        figuras[0]="♥";
        figuras[1]="♣";
        figuras[2]="♠";
        figuras[3]="♦";


        if(boton == juegoNuevo){ 
            for(i=0;i<8;i++){

            cartas[i].setEnabled(true); cartas[i].setLabel("*********");
                 cartas[i].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
               }

            marcador.setText("Juego nuevo"); 
            juegoNuevo.setEnabled(false);
            return; 

        }

        if(boton == cartas[0]){

                    cartas[0].setLabel(figuras[Memorando.list.get(0)]);
                }

                    if(boton == cartas[1]){
                        int numAleatorio=(int) (Math.random()*4);
                        cartas[1].setLabel(figuras[numAleatorio]);
                        }
                    if(boton == cartas[2]){
                        int numAleatorio=(int) (Math.random()*4);
                                cartas[2].setLabel(figuras[numAleatorio]);
                            }
                    if(boton == cartas[3]){
                        int numAleatorio=(int) (Math.random()*4);
                                cartas[3].setLabel(figuras[numAleatorio]);
                            }
                    if(boton == cartas[4]){
                        int numAleatorio=(int) (Math.random()*4);
                                cartas[4].setLabel(figuras[numAleatorio]);
                            }
                    if(boton == cartas[5]){
                        int numAleatorio=(int) (Math.random()*4);
                                cartas[5].setLabel(figuras[numAleatorio]);
                            }
                    if(boton == cartas[6]){
                        int numAleatorio=(int) (Math.random()*4);
                                cartas[6].setLabel(figuras[numAleatorio]);
                            }
                    if(boton == cartas[7]){
                        int numAleatorio=(int) (Math.random()*4);
                                cartas[7].setLabel(figuras[numAleatorio]);
                            }
    }


            void finDelJuego(){
                juegoNuevo.setEnabled(true);
                for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
                    cartas[i].setEnabled(false);
                }
            }


        }
```

The error I'm getting is 
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: Could you please be more clear and more concise, tell us what and where is the problem you are getting.

Comment: The error I'm getting is Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say as we don't have evidence on how/whether you call all these methods, but I can tell you that I noticed you have a member variable `list`, but in the `random()` method you declare and use a **local variable** that may cover the **member variable**. So, the member variable `list` may remain empty, and when you try to access it in `actionPerformed()` then the 'empty' member variable `list` is used, so any index would be out of bounds.

So, I would suggest that you remove the declaration of the `list` from within the `random` method.

Comment: The random is used in the other buttons, I only used the list to check if it runs, what I'm trying to do is to generate a random number for every button without repeating it, could you please help me?

Comment: Do you have a line number where this exception occurs? Which is the array that is empty and you are trying to access an index out of the bounds?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0 I think the array list is the problem

Comment: You also have a Strings list `cartas` and another `figuras`. They are suspects also. However, you are using `Memorando.list.get(0)` but the list is not populated according to the provided code. Do you populate the list in another way that is not shown?